# Movement without Riggibody

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How to do without Rigidbody, rotate the object along the Y axis in both directions, and move the object forward in the right direction? How can you add acceleration and inertia to an object?

Comment: Using the [transform](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html) property of an [Object](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.html)

Comment: You can change the transform of your game object in the update function. What have you tried to that effect?

Comment: Is this one of those _how can I go swimming without getting wet_ questions?  If you forgo the physics engine that is Rigidbody, then you'll have to update the transform of the object manually.  You can do your own physics calculations with a little calculus and numerical integration or embed some other physics engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at the Unity Documentation [Here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxis.html), or look at code provided.

```
float horizontalSpeed = 2.0f;
float verticalSpeed = 2.0f;
float speed = 10.0f;

void Movement()
{
    // Get the horizontal and vertical axis.
    // By default they are mapped to the arrow keys.
    // The value is in the range -1 to 1
    float x = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    float z = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

    // Make it move 10 meters per second instead of 10 meters per frame...
    var moveVector = new Vector3(x, 0 , 0);

    // Move translation along the object's z-axis
    transform.Translate(moveVector * Time.deltaTime);

}

void Rotation()
{
    // Get the mouse delta. This is not in the range -1...1
    float h = horizontalSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
    float v = verticalSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");

    transform.Rotate(v, h, 0);
}
```